# SharePoint 2010 search crawling but not displaying results

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, web-crawler

I have searched for possible solutions for days, but have had no luck at getting my SharePoint 2010 to return search results.

The search was working, but was only returning results from a subsite. I have gone through many blog posts and sites on setting up the search and still nothing. My last resort was to delete the search and reimplement it.

The search crawls just fine (no errors). Here are a couple of the blogs and sites I have tried (out of the many), but nothing seems to help.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/688b5c52-f478-463b-bc00-debfd0c3be2b

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010/

My setup is an intranet on a VM with SQL 2008 R2 (nothing out of the ordinary for the server, single farm). The search account has the rights to Full Read and is also included on all page permissions.

Here is a look at the log descriptions when a search is performed (no access denied errors). These results are all from the "Query Processor" category.

```
(w3wp.exe) PluggableSecurityTrimmerManager:SetSearchApplicationToUse: Set SearchApplication to 'Search Service Application'

(w3wp.exe) Resetting cookie: Old value = '', new value = 'nautilusRankDescending'

(mssearch.exe) 63239349-6356-4a02-96db-c40ffb223572-query-0: Query completed 109 ms, detailed time:  Query stage execution ms times: 62 47 0 0 47 0 0 0   Query stage cpu ms times: 31 15 0 0 15 0 0 0   Query stage hit counts: 1 1 1 7 2 0 0 0   Cursor count: 13  Mapped page count: 16  Total index count: 1    [srequest.cxx:5526]  d:\office\source\search\native\ytrip\tripoli\cifrmwrk\srequest.cxx

(w3wp.exe) Completed query execution with timings: total:140 dup:0 sec:0 join:0 ft:109 sql:31. Join Retry: 0. Security Trimming Retry: 0. Duplicate removal Retry: 0.
```

I am thoroughly baffled. Hopefully someone has had the same problem and can share how they fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It has been quite the headache getting this to work. Below are some suggestions or check points to keep in mind. I hope they might help someone else out there.

- if you have tried everything and you still don't have your search working delete the SSA and start over. I did this and then went through step by step
- Set up a proper service/system account to handle the search.
- Make sure that your application pool is started (at one time for some reason mine had stopped itself

I utilized this well documented article about setting up a search to rewalk myself through the process (after I deleted my initial search).

http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/search-configuration-in-sharepoint-2010/

It has screen shots and useful tips for setting up scopes and crawl rules, etc.

Comment: I had this same issue but I added a "Basic Search Center" page and wired it to our top-level site and could see the results.

Answer (score 2):

One of the mistakes that we made is to use default Network Service account for the Application Pool. Make sure that you set up a separate domain\user account e.g. sp_search for search purpose.