# sharepoint 2010 search not returning results

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, settings

I have searched unsuccessfully for a number of days to try and resolve an issue with the search not returning results in Sharepoint 2010.  Basically the search has successfully crawled the content and indexed the results but the search is returning no results on our site.
The codebase is the same as other servers that does return results so we are confident it's not a coding issue, but is a sharepoint issue.  We can reach the search queryex webservice also

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on possible settings / things to check to try and kickstart this search!

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please advise if I haven't added enough detail.

Comment: Have you set up all of the required managed metadata properties?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to SO myself, but I'll help if I can! Quick couple of questions:

- Is the search returning no results for all user types, including admin?
- Is there an error returned when you submit a search or does it just say "no results"?
- Are you using any custom web parts for displaying the search results, or is it OOB?
- Do you have access to the ULS logs perchance? There may be further information there.
- Are you using search scopes at all?
- What domain account are you using for the search app pool? There's some info here about making sure you have the right type of identity - [SharePoint 2010 search crawling but not displaying results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066807/sharepoint-2010-search-crawling-but-not-displaying-results)

(Apologies for posting a comment-as-an-answer, but since my rep is below 50 I can't yet post comments on your question - still wanted to help though.)